# Can I use a link tag to preconnect to a WebSocket destination?

Tags: html, websocket, preconnect

I have a website that uses WebSockets to connect to the server and transfer data.

At *[css-tricks.com](//css-tricks.com)*, they showed the following example for using HTML link tag preconnect:

`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://css-tricks.com">`

Can I use this to connect to WebSockets, or at least speed it up? Something like this

`<link rel="preconnect" href="`**wss**`://css-tricks.com">`

Is there a way I can tell if it is even working when I try the WS connection? Or even with the HTTP connection?

Comment: Do you try to put the wss connection in a jsfile and do the preconnect to the jsfile ?